# Error on starting terminal every time

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal

I seem to be getting this error every time I open up terminal and don't know where the problem might be. I had successfully installed apache spark the last time I used terminal. On starting it up the next time onwards I seem to be facing this error. I believe the error might be in the bashrc file but I dont know how to correct it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/spark/bin': not a valid identifier
```

Comment: If you suspect the .bashrc file, then why don't you show it in your question?

Comment: `bash -x ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you have

```
export PATH = $PATH:/usr/local/spark/bin
```

with spaces. It should be:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/spark/bin
```

No spaces.